# setDrawerLayout(androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout) is deprecated

Tags: android-studio, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer, appbar

I am trying set up Navigation Drawer Layout with App Bar Configuration using the new Android Architecture. The problem am having is that android studio is telling me the way am setting up the drawer layout is deprecated.

Here is my xml configuration

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/top_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"/>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Design">

        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is how i declare the AppBarConfiguration and Drawer Layout

```
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private NavController navController;
    MaterialToolbar topAppBar;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
```

Here is where i find the NavController, topAppBar, drawerLayout and NavigationView

```
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        topAppBar = findViewById(R.id.top_app_bar);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
```

Here is the way am setting the drawer layout which is deprecated is there a new way of setting up the drawer layout that is not deprecated

```
    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
                        .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                        .build();
```

Here is where am setting up with the NavigatioUi

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(topAppBar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

use the [`setOpenableLayout(@Nullable Openable openableLayout)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/AppBarConfiguration.Builder#setOpenableLayout(androidx.customview.widget.Openable)) method of
[`AppBarConfiguration.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/AppBarConfiguration.Builder)

`DrawerLayout` implements `Openable`.

### Example

```java
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()) 
.setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
.build();
```

Comment: how can we use this method, can you add this code also, I think this will help others.

Comment: appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
                        .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
                        .build();

Comment: Implements where? in the Drawer main class?

Comment: See package androidx.drawerlayout.widget. public class DrawerLayout extends ViewGroup implements Openable

Answer (score 18):

It's ironic that the latest Android Studio (v 4.0.1) itself uses `setDrawerLayout(drawer)` in its inbuilt `NavigationDrawerActivity` example.

The fix is very simple. Here's probably what you have:

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)           // REPLACE THIS LINE
                .build();
```

Replace the above mentioned line with the following:

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)        // WITH THIS LINE
                .build();
```

Source: [Android Official Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/AppBarConfiguration.Builder#setDrawerLayout(androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout))

The `DrawerLayout` class implements `Openable`. So this will simply work without requiring any other change from your end.